# Difference between './file' and 'sh file'

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, shell, zsh

On macOS, in the zsh terminal, I ran the following commands:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir newdir
cd newdir
touch file1
./file1
```

The last command returned
`zsh: permission denied: ./file1`

But running
`sh file1`
executed the file with no errors.

I've read about how running `sh filename` executes the file using the sh interpreter explicitly. The sh interpreter has additional permissions that allow it to run `file1`.

However, I also read that `./file1` executes `file1` using the default interpreter, in my case `zsh`. So I tried to run

```
zsh file1
```

But this also executed the file without errors.

### The question:

Why doesn't the interactive shell have permission to run the file, but at the same time has permission to execute using the interpreters `sh, bash, zsh`?

Additionally, looking at the permissions of `sh, bash, zsh` in the `\bin` directory shows that the `other` group has execute permissions on them:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   1.3M Sep 16 16:28 zsh
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   1.2M Sep 16 16:28 bash
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   131K Sep 16 16:28 sh
```

Doesn't this mean any user can run any file using the interpreters which possess additional permissions?

Comment: Try executing `chmod +x ./file1` before entering `./file1`. [There's a bit more info here](https://superuser.com/a/117706/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The sh interpreter has additional permissions that allow it to run file1.

No, it doesn't.

> So why doesn't the interactive shell have permission to run the file, but at the same time has permission to execute using the interpreters sh, bash, zsh?

Interpreters don't actually "run" or "execute" the script file at all, as far as the OS is concerned. They only *read* it – and then they do stuff according to what's in the file. (Hence the name 'interpreter'.)

So when you do `sh myfile`, what happens is that 'sh' reads a line, calls chdir(); reads a line, spawns `/bin/mkdir`; reads a line, calls chdir() again; reads a line, spawns `/bin/touch`; … – the OS doesn't really know or care that those actions are done on behalf of a script.

(On systems such as macOS or Windows, the interpreter might *deliberately* inform the OS that it's processing a certain script, for auditing or security policy purposes, but it doesn't have to.)

For scripts, the 'execute' permission is mostly just there for convenience (and integration – together with `#!/bin/xxx` headers it allows scripts to look and act like standard executables), not as any kind of security measure.

> Doesn't this mean any user can run any file using the interpreters which possess additional permissions?

Any user can "run" any file using any interpreter, as long as the interpreter *itself* is executable.

That is, the '+x' permission on /bin/zsh only lets the user execute /bin/zsh itself – it doesn't grant zsh any special rights beyond what the user already has.

(There are ways to grant an executable some special rights, such as the 'setuid' flag or Linux "file capabilities" – making an interpreter 'setuid' would then grant the same rights to any script in interprets – but that's normally not done.)

Comment: So what's the difference between ```sh myfile``` and ```./myfile```? Why does the first command 'work' and the second doesn't?

Comment: The first command asks the OS to execute `/bin/sh` specifically, with nothing about the script file – the word "myfile" is passed to the interpreter as regular text and the interpreter opens it as a regular file. Whereas the second command asks the OS to execute `./myfile` specifically (the OS itself reads its header to determine the interpreter). It's all about what consists the actual 'command' (1st word) of the input – that's what is given to the OS for execution.

Comment: (Although, since in your case there is no `#!` header in your script, when you do './myfile' the OS actually returns "not something I recognize" and your interactive shell sneakily falls back to the 1st method anyway, running 'sh myfile' behind the scenes and making the +x permission moot either way... But ignore that for the moment.)

Comment: Thank you, your answer along with the answer referenced by @Gairfowl cleared this up for me.